# Where is the block assignment file linking 2010 Census data with 113th congressional districts?

Tags: government, us-census, district

The [block assignment files](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/baf.html) from the US Census are very nice.  Unfortunately, they appear to tell you which census blocks make up each district in the 112th congress.  This makes some sense, since this is the congress that was elected in 2010.  However, the 2010 census was used to create the districts for the 113th congress, so it is natural to want to know which 2010 census blocks make up each 113th congressional district.

What I want is a file that tells me, for each census block, which 113th congressional district that block is in.  In other words, exactly like the existing block assginment files, but for the 113th congress instead of the 112th.  I can't find any such file on the census website or in my wanderings through the FTP.  Where is this information?

Comment: That block assignment file link is dead

Answer (score 5):

In accordance with the inimitable "logic" of the Census website, the files in question are not located with the other block assignment files.  Rather they are on a "[113th & 114th Congressional and 2012 & 2014 State Legislative District Plans](http://www.census.gov/rdo/data/113th_congressional_and_2012_state_legislative_district_plans.html)" page under "Redistricting Data".  Even on this page, do not be fooled into thinking that the section labeled "113th Congressional District Relationship Files" contains the files specifying the relationship between congressional districts and census blocks.  No, that page contains only relationships between districts and certain *other* geographies, such as counties and school districts.  If you want the relationship between congressional (and state legislative) districts and census blocks, you must scroll down to the section labeled "113th Congress and 2012 State Legislative Block Equivalency Files", a name which is logical enough but whose position relative to seemingly similar data I find quite baffling.

Comment: This link is dead

Answer (score 2):

The resource I use for conversion of one weird U.S. geography to another is [Missouri Census Data Center](https://mcdc.missouri.edu/applications/geocorr.html). In particular, they have the 113th Congress, but miss the 112th Congress. You can ask them why if you are sufficiently curious :).

Comment: This link is dead