# Crosswalk from US Census Block to Congressional District

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, us-census

The [Census geographic hierarchy diagram](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/reference/geodiagram.pdf) indicates that Congressional Districts are built from Census Blocks. However, I don't see any crosswalks from blocks to congressional districts on the Census [Congressional District Relationship Files](https://www.census.gov/geographies/reference-files/time-series/geo/relationship-files.2010.html#par_textimage_1589730557) website section. I also couldn't find such a crosswalk on sites like NHGIS, though I did just [ask on the IPUMS forum](https://forum.ipums.org/t/joining-data-on-congressional-districts/3670/17?u=max_ghenis).

A [similar question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/where-is-the-block-assignment-file-linking-2010-census-data-with-113th-congressi) was asked in 2015, but it asked about a specific past congressional session, and all the links in questions and answers are now dead.

Specifically I'm most interested in a crosswalk from 2010 Census Block to 117th (current) Congressional District, but ideally would like to know a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crosswalk from 2010 Census block to 116th Congressional District: https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/2019/dec/rdo/116-congressional-district-bef.html